# Linux driver that supports 10.5 inch HDMI waveshare display

Tags: linux

[image]Hope you are doing well!

I have connected i.MX8M NANO EVK to the 10.5-inch AMOLED display and the display is not able to run the application, attached image FYR.

The following problems are observed:
The display when connected to i.MX 8M NANO board is booting up correctly but not able to display/run the application (developed and booted up for display).
The display after booting up shows the error as "failed to start terminate psplash-quit.service" which can be observed in SSH terminal, image attached FYR.
The display mirrors when connected to a laptop using HDMI cable and also works as a monitor when booted linux from CPU.

Kindly, do guide me for what is this error coming and also steps to resolve the error as early as possible.

Thanks & regards,
Rohan R E

Answer (score 0):

The [i.MX Graphics User's Guide](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/IMX_GRAPHICS_USERS_GUIDE.pdf) says on page 33:* "i.MX 8 on Linux OS supports Direct Rendering Manager (DRM) where the Linux framebuffer support is limited, recommended to Graphics Buffer Manager (GBM)."*

The Psplash boot splash screen probably also uses the kernel framebuffer drivers: if there is no sufficiently functional framebuffer driver in kernel for this hardware, starting the boot splash will fail, and so the "Terminate Psplash Boot Screen" task will also fail because it will find nothing to stop.

You might be able to fix the error message by simply `systemctl disable psplash-quit.service` because it is unnecessary in the current state. But the root cause is that the kernel framebuffer driver for the i.MX 8 GPU does not exist or is not sufficiently functional for the `psplash` boot splash screen: if your application is also designed to use the framebuffer API, it might also be unable to display anything.

There are several possible APIs for graphical applications in the Linux ecosystem:

- the kernel framebuffer API (fb)
- the raw Direct Rendering Manager (DRM) API
- GBM API, available at least as part of the Mesa OpenGL implementation or with `openwfd` (= open-source Miracast implementation), possibly as part of other graphics drivers too
- X11 (which can include Mesa OpenGL and GBM)
- Wayland (which can include Mesa OpenGL and GBM)

It is not clear which of these APIs your application is designed to use.

The *i.MX Graphics User's Guide* seems to suggest that the framebuffer support is not (yet?) fully functional, and so the display might activate only when the appropriate X11/Wayland drivers are loaded and the GUI is activated.

Newer kernels also offer `simpledrmfb`, which is a compatibility layer that might allow the use of the framebuffer API on hardware that has only DRM drivers (might require that the hardware + DRM driver presents a "simple" enough interface to allow it be supported by this compatibility layer).